# Javascript ignoring if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm somewhat new to Javascript. I'm trying to make it so that clicking on an image on one page takes you to a new page and shows a specific div on that new page, so I used sessionStorage to remember and booleans to keep track of which image is being clicked. Right now, the code always executes the first if statement, regardless of which image is clicked. This code works fine in normal java so  I can't figure out why my if statements are being ignored in javascript. I also tried adding an 'else' at the end, and tried ===. Here's my javscript, and thank you!

```
 sessionStorage.clickedLeft;
 sessionStorage.clickedMiddle;
 sessionStorage.clickedRight;

         function openedProjectFromGallery() {
    if(sessionStorage.clickedLeft) {
        $(".left-project-pop-up").show();
    } else if (sessionStorage.clickedMiddle) {
        $(".middle-project-pop-up").show();
    } else if (sessionStorage.clickedRight) {
        $(".right-project-pop-up").show();
            }
    sessionStorage.clickedLeft = false;
    sessionStorage.clickedMiddle = false;
    sessionStorage.clickedRight = false;
}

   $("document").ready(function () {


   $(".pop-up .x-button").click(function(){
    $(".pop-up").hide();
});

   $(".project-description .x-button").click(function(){
    $(".project-pop-up").hide();

});

$(".left-project-thumb img").on("click", ".left-project-thumb img", function(){
    sessionStorage.clickedLeft = true;
    sessionStorage.clickedMiddle = false;
    sessionStorage.clickedRight = false;
    openedProjectFromGallery();
});

$(".profile-left-project img").click(function(){
    $(".left-project-pop-up").show(1000);

});

$(".middle-project-thumb img").on("click", ".middle-project-thumb img", (function(){
    sessionStorage.clickedMiddle = true;
    sessionStorage.clickedLeft = false;
    sessionStorage.clickedRight = false;
    openedProjectFromGallery();

});

$(".profile-middle-project img").click(function(){
    $(".middle-project-pop-up").show(1000);

});

$(".right-project-thumb img").on("click", ".right-project-thumb img", (function(){
    sessionStorage.clickedRight = true;
    sessionStorage.clickedLeft = false;
    sessionStorage.clickedMiddle = false;
    openedProjectFromGallery();

});

$(".profile-right-project img").click(function(){
    $(".right-project-pop-up").show(1000);

});


  });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: apparently you are calling `openedProjectFromGallery` when the script file is loaded, which is before any click event can have happened.

Comment: Create a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/), please!

Answer (score 1):

You are defining function openedProjectFromGallery() with in document.ready . Define it outside document.ready and also give your three booleans some initial value at the top of your code if not initialized with some value or they are empty. I hope this would help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really answer to your orginal question,as the main issue with your code is, as @njzk2 says, that `openProjectFromGallery` only being called once, and not on each event, however I wanted to put my two coins on how this code could look like.

This is good example where custom events should be used

```
$(document).on('showPopup', function( e, popup ) {
    $('.'+popup + '-project-pop-up').show()
})

$(document).on('hidePopup', function( e ) {
    $('.popup').hide()
})

$('.left-project-thumb img').on('click', function(e) {
    $(document).trigger('showPopup', ['left'])
})

$('.right-project-thumb img').on('click', function(e) {
    $(document).trigger('showPopup', ['right'])
})
```

I think you get an idea.

On the other hand, it always nice to use event delegation with a lot of similar events as well as dom data.

```
<div class='popup' data-popup='left'>
   <img />
</div>   

$(document).on('click','.popup', function( e ) {
     $(document).trigger('showPopup', [$(this).data('popup')])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see openedProjectFromGallery is only getting called on document load.

Add a call to it into each of the event handling functions or use [jQuery's delegate function](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to assign event handling to each image.